# Uninstalled CleanMyMac still shows notifications

Tags: macos, software

I had installed CleanMyMac before, and have already uninstalled it.

However, I got the notification saying "It's time to clean your mac".

How is this possible and how can I avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The interesting thing about uninstalling CleanMyMac is that the best application for the job is, in fact CleanMyMac.

If you set it to uninstall itself, it will tidily clean up its own leftovers before finally quitting & trashing itself.

It is, in fact, probably quicker to re-install it, then get it to uninstall itself than to pick apart where the leftovers are.

Ref: MacPaw FAQs
[How To Uninstall CleanMyMac 2?](http://macpaw.com/support/cleanmymac2/knowledgebase/how-to-uninstall-cleanmymac-2)  &
[How to Uninstall CleanMyMac 3](http://macpaw.com/support/cleanmymac/knowledgebase/how-to-uninstall-cleanmymac-3)

Comment: The problem is, once you upgrade to macOS Sierra CleanMyMac 2 no longer runs, so it can't be used to uninstall itself.

Answer (score 8):

go to your command line, `~/Library/LaunchAgents` and remove the `.plist` file reading `cleanmymac`

Comment: To add twopence, removal is `sudo rm` for example, `sudo rm com.macpaw.CleanMyMac3.Scheduler.plist`, you can find the exact file name using `ls` in folder `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. Imho, this answer is the right-one for technically-able users.

Answer (score 3):

Open System Preferences / Notifications / Scroll down till Clean My Mac is visible and uncheck all the boxes. Done.

Comment: This solution will not clean leftover files

Comment: Also the notifications seem to reset themselves back on after a restart

Comment: To stop them coming back on reboot, System Prefs / Users & Groups / Login Items. Remove CleanMyMac from the list.